# How to write SQL Query for this case?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Suppose I have a tableA -

id  value
   1   a
   2   d

tableB

idTableA someValue someOtherValue
   1        d          e
   1        x          y

Now in tableB I want to insert rows where idTableA would come from tableA and custom values in somevalue and someOtherValue.

I want to write a query like this:

```
insert into B (idTableA,someValue,someOtherValue)
values(idTableAValue, 'value1', 'value2') 
(select idTableA from TableA )
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into B (idTableA, someValue, someOtherValue)
select idTableA, 'value1', 'value2' 
from TableA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps